# How to check whether integer contains 0 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, integer

Im trying to pull bunch of records from MySQL with condition whether the column value contains 0. If I convert to string and check with contains (%0%), it takes more time to execute.. Is there any short way to check on Integer column? Thank you..

Comment: Why do you need such check? Performing a string operation on a integer column is always slower than straight artithmetics. Please explain the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: We are writing a query to display the customer_id,customer full name ,city,pincode,and -- order details (order id,order date, product class desc, product desc, subtotal(product_quantity * product_price)) -- for orders shipped to cities whose pin codes do not have any 0s in them. And sort the output on customer name, order date and subtotal.

Comment: How many digits is your pin?

Comment: We have 6 digits pin

Comment: Shouldn't pin be string? It's like zipcode or phone number, you don't do arithmetic on it.

Comment: I need to extract records which do not contain 0 in zipcode

Comment: Simply add according CHECK constraint over this column into the table structure - and the presence of the value with zero digit in it will be impossible. Recommended check is `REGEXP '^[1-9]{6}$'`.

Comment: In described situation you must take into account that pin must be > 111110. Because, for example, entered `012345` which will be stored as 12354 will match `NOT LIKE '%0%'` check.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably run a regex on the integer column. Something like below.

`SELECT fieldname FROM tablename WHERE fieldname REGEX '[0]';`

About the performance, I believe that LIKE is faster than REGEX. But since your LIKE involves string conversion, this would have some difference in execution time

Comment: REGEXP converts the argument to string too.

Comment: It's supposed to be REGEXP and not REGEX. Also it should be REGEXP '^[0]$' if you want the value to be 0 and not just to contain 0

Answer (score 0):

@SriniK You can use either `POSITION()` or `LOCATE()` in conjunction with `CONVERT()` to convert the column value into a string and then find if the string "0" exists within the string. Both of these functions return a positive number greater than 0 indicating the index of the substring within your string and they return a 0 if the string isn't found.

Here's how to create a simple test table to illustrate:

```
CREATE TABLE `testTable` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `someNum` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(`id`));
                          
INSERT INTO `testTable` (`someNum`)
VALUES
(1),
(10),
(11),
(100),
(111),
(222),
(210);
```

And here are two queries illustrating both `POSITION()` and `LOCATE()`:

```
SELECT `id`,
    `someNum`,
    POSITION('0' IN CONVERT(`someNum`, CHAR))
FROM `testTable`
WHERE POSITION('0' IN CONVERT(`someNum`, CHAR)) > 0
;
                              
SELECT `id`,
    `someNum`,
    LOCATE('0', CONVERT(`someNum`, CHAR))
FROM `testTable`
WHERE LOCATE('0', CONVERT(`someNum`, CHAR)) > 0
;
```

[I have mocked this up on dbfiddle here so you can get a better look at it.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6e5jCc3eWRR7XyYfoTpWSR/0)

If this doesn't get you what you need or if you don't understand something please leave a comment with details and I'll do what I can to help further. Good luck.